# How Can I write the test case for the method which takes interface as a argument?

Tags: testing, junit, mocking, mockito, code-coverage

```
protected CustomerDeviceView setDeviceViewForSerialNumber(ResultSet rs) {
        CustomerDeviceView customerDeviceView = new CustomerDeviceView();
        try {

            customerDeviceView.setNumber(rs.getString(DeviceConstants.DBFIELD_UDI_SN));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SystemException(e.getMessage());
        }
        return customerDeviceView;
    }
```

```
@Test
    public void testsetDeviceViewForSerialNumber()throws Exception{
        try {
        deviceDaoImpl.setDeviceViewForSerialNumber(any());
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

I tried with the above test case and showing code coverage is very low for this. Please help me out how I can implement the method which takes interface as a argument and how we can mock the Interface. I am very new to this junit please help me out

Answer (score 0):

For your `setDeviceViewForSerialNumber` method you can make two differnt types of tests.

The first test can be a test covering your success case, that means returning a `CustomerDeviceView`, which you can compare to an expected object.

```
@Test
public void testSuccessCase() throws Exception {
    // creating the expected value
    CustomerDeviceView expected = /* something */;
    
    // The result of rs.getString(DeviceConstants.DBFIELD_UDI_SN)
    String myResult = "something";

    // creating a mock object of ResultSet 
    ResultSet rs = Mockito.mock(ResultSet.class);
    
    // returning myResult when calling rs.getString(DeviceConstants.DBFIELD_UDI_SN)
    Mockito.doReturn(myResult).when(rs).getString(DeviceConstants.DBFIELD_UDI_SN);


    // calling the method with the mock object
    CustomerDeviceView  actual =  deviceDaoImpl.setDeviceViewForSerialNumber(rs);

    // comparing the result from the method and the expected value
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

The second test can be a test covering your error case, that means that your `setDeviceViewForSerialNumber` method is throwing an `SystemException` because of an `Exception is thrown`.

```
@Test
public void testErrorCase() throws Exception {

    // creating a mock object of ResultSet 
    ResultSet rs = Mockito.mock(ResultSet.class);
    
    // throwing a exception when calling rs.getString(DeviceConstants.DBFIELD_UDI_SN)
    Mockito.doThrow(new RuntimeException("junit").when(rs).getString(DeviceConstants.DBFIELD_UDI_SN);


    // asserting that the SystemException is thrown
    assertThrows(SystemException.class, () -> deviceDaoImpl.setDeviceViewForSerialNumber(rs));

}
```

Both test cases are working with [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/).
In both cases, you will need to create a mock object via `Mockito.mock(ResultSet.class)`. This mock object has the default behaviour to return `null` for every method call. Also none of the methods has any logic.

By using `doReturn(myResult).when(rs).getString(DeviceConstants.DBFIELD_UDI_SN);` we are telling Mockito to return `myResult` when calling `rs.getString(DeviceConstants.DBFIELD_UDI_SN)`. For any other methods of the object and for any other parameters, e.g. `rs.getString("lorem");`, there will be still returned `null`.

By using `doThrow(new RuntimeException("junit").when(rs).getString(DeviceConstants.DBFIELD_UDI_SN);` we are giving Mockito the task to throw a `RuntimeException` when calling `rs.getString(DeviceConstants.DBFIELD_UDI_SN)`. It will, similar to the upper case, just throw an `RuntimeException` for the given method and parameter.
Please note that you only can throw Exceptions that are thrown by the original method. That means, if your method is not throwing any `IOException`, you can not use `doThrow(new IOException("junit").when(rs).getString(DeviceConstants.DBFIELD_UDI_SN);`.